# Проблема с регулярным выражением

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, java-ee

Не могу понять, в чем проблема. Написал регулярное выражения для определения строчки

`GUID {2bfe45c0-ffff-34af-abcd-ef4535243454}`

Вот мое регулярное выражение:

```
Pattern guidPattern = Pattern.compile("^\{?[0-9a-f0-F]{8}\-([0-9a-f0-F]{4}\-){3}[0-9a-f0-F]{12} \}?$");
```

Выдает:

> Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \ )

Answer (score 1):

Символы \ надо экранировать. Я Вашу регулярку не тестировал, но попробуйте:

```
Pattern guidPattern = Pattern.compile("^\\{?[0-9a-f0-F]{8}\\-([0-9a-f0-F]{4}\\-){3}[0-9a-f0-F]{12} \\}?$");
```

Затестил. Вам нужно:

```
Pattern guidPattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\{[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\\-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}\\})?$");
```

Comment: И я посоветую пользоваться онлайн-сервисами для проверки. Например, этим: http://regex101.com/r/uV3sO1/1 . Когда составите правильную регулярку, то удвойте все символы '\' при переносе в ява-строку.

Comment: @bvn13, Ваше регулярное выражение посчитает пустую строку верным гуидом.

Comment: @ReinRaus, а так? Pattern guidPattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\{[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\\-([0-9a-fA-F]{4}\\-){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}\\}){1}$");